# Acces local variable from a class.new ruby

Tags: ruby, scope

I have a question about scopes in ruby, why the `baz` method cannot access the variable `foo`, it seems counter intuitive because the scope of `baz` is contained in that of `create_B`

```rb
class A
  def self.create_B(foo)
    Class.new do 
       def baz
         p foo
       end
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
A.create_B(4).new.baz
NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for #<#<Class:0x00007f3a31bddf18>:0x00007f3a31bdde28>
from (pry):23:in `baz'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `def` keyword creates a new scope. In order to access variables that were defined outside, you can use the [`define_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Module.html#define_method-method) method:

```
class A
  def self.create_B(foo)
    Class.new do 
       define_method(:baz) do
         p foo
       end
    end
  end
end

A.create_B(4).new.baz
#=> 4
```